# How suggestion works in elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene

I am aware about the phrase and term suggesters in elasticsearch.
But I want to know how data is internally matched and returned in elasticsearch? Also the spellcheck too.

How scoring is done in elasticsearch suggester?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out how suggestion works at [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html).

> The meaning of the score depends on the used suggester. The term
>   suggester’s score is based on the edit distance.

Answer (score 0):

Internally elasticsearch uses the following method for suggestions.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzziness.html